# How to write a unit test for a wicket DownloadLink?

Tags: java, unit-testing, wicket

I'm building unittests for a wicketproject and I'm having trouble testing a download function. I start from a page with a search form.

```
wicketTester.startPage(SearchPage.class);
// set values for FormTester formTester
formTester.submit();
```

after submission I get a page with a ListView, so far so good.

```
tester.assertRenderedPage(ResultPage.class);
// test some Labels in listitems
```

Now I want to export the list to a csv and check the file. Still Ok here

```
tester.clickLink("exportlink");
tester.assertContains("part,of,csv,to,test;");
```

Now I want to "go back" and click a listitem to go to the details of a search results. I cant find how to get the previous page where the list is and then trigger the ajaxevent on the listitem.

```
tester.executeAjaxEvent("aansluitngrow:1", "onclick");
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the way you're unit testing is correct. Each unit test is supposed to test a single feature of a unit, so in this context it would be: 
1. testing submitting a form; 
2. testing the export link 
3. testing the ajax event; 
etc.

Each of these points should have their own unit test, as each of them is a single unit of work. That way you can be sure that any combination of these units will also be functional. While if you test a single path through these units you cannot ensure that if one of the elements in the path differs, you will still get a correct result.

Additionally, 'back' is not a feature of your code base; you should not include it in your tests, you should just assume that whatever provides the back functionality is already tested.

For that reason I believe that you don't even need to 'go back'; you should conduct a new unit test for that functionality, where the starting point is the `ResultPage` with a correctly rendered item list (correct rendering being ensured in another test), on which you execute your custom ajax event.

Comment: All the "Real" unit tests are already in place. This is more of a system test. I'm using this to recreate a few scenarios to test if the components together also work. Of course I can split this up and mock/stub input but this test is supposed to be a bit more than that. I also what to test logic here.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure if this would work, but you could try to save the previously rendered page in a local field via [`BaseWicketTester#getLastRenderedPage()`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/BaseWicketTester.html#getLastRenderedPage%28%29) and after testing the link you could use [`BaseWicketTester#startPage(T)`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/BaseWicketTester.html#startPage%28T%29) to simulate the 'back' functionality. I'm not sure if you can do anything more specific than that.